# Objective c-How to move a marker up and down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

How to move the black marker over the image?

```
value=0+arc4random()%(100-0+1)...
CGFloat orignY=backgroundImage.frame.origin.y-(backgroundImage.frame.origin.y-0)*(value-0)/100;
marker.frame=CGRectMake(22,originY,width,height);
```

Tried this ,i get some random values and need to move the marker according to the value.

if value= 50 ,then marker should be at the center of the image..

How to achieve this....please help..

Comment: Be sure to have the code executed on the main thread

Comment: your code is fine, but the question is how often you call this code and where you call this code.

Comment: its in a timer i generate the random values @Mr.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the min and  max values say

```
  min=0,max=100
```

and let the first position of the marker be at the end of the image..so we get the y axis at that point.
set

```
 oldY=marker.frame.origin.y
```

in the function to move the marker

```
 marker.frame=CGRectMake(marker.frame.origin.x,oldY-(valuetomove-min)*heightofbackgroundimage/(max-min),marker.frame.size.width,marker.frame.size.height)
```